# JavaScript selector by class prefix?

Tags: javascript, css

in CSS, we can select multiple classes with same prefix like: 'pre-1','pre-2',... with this line of code:

```
[class^="pre-"]
```

Is there any way in Javascript that I can get the same result in Javascript? Thank you!

The result I want to achieve is for Javascript code.

Comment: No! This is for Javascript not for CSS!

Comment: Why -1 me?! This is not the same question!

Comment: The selectors in CSS can be used in JavaScript as it is. So, in your case you can use `document.querySelectorAll('div[class^="pre-"], div[class*=" pre-"]')`

Answer (score 5):

Use plain JavaScript

```
document.querySelectorAll('div[class^="pre-"]')
```

or

Use jquery **starts with** attribute selector
 `Selector [name^="value"]`

```
$('[class^="pre-"]')
```

More [here](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/66bw5u4h/88/